# Grainy Camera Filter Style

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera, effects, shadows

Low poly works can look good with grainy rendering, but turning down the samples makes the shadows looks horrible.  How do I create a grainy effect to my render? It can be in blender or post processing (in photoshop). See work below: [image]

I want that type of effect and a solution in blender cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These effects are generally achieved in post production, they are mostly render engine independent, so they should work both for Cycles or any other engine without requiring that you  re-rendering you image. You can easily tweak the effects in a flexible non destructive way without ruining your work or having to wait for a long time.

These are done through compositing, check the [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/index.html) about it.
You probably want to look into the *Distort* type of nodes or *Filter* nodes.

If non satisfy your particular needs perhaps look into making it in an image editing software like GIMP or Photoshop